# xp_subdirs permission denied

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, jobs, sql-server-data-tools

Getting execute permission denied when running:

```
DECLARE @RootPath VARCHAR(1000) = '\\SomeUNCPath\SubFolder\'
...
EXEC master.sys.xp_subdirs @RootPath
```

from a job that calls a package and the package has a single SQL Execute task. I set full control for user "everyone" on the folder so I do not know where else to look. The package has a different connection to where the package is deployed to and thus where the job has been created and the connection is using Windows Authentication. In the "View Context" page in SQL Server messages the Caller is not me but rather a fictitious user but that should not matter if everyone has full control.

The SQL code works fine in SQL Server Management Studio if I logon to the server using windows authentication and works fine if run in the context of Visual Studio - so I assume it runs as me in both cases.

When I run the package I get the error:

> 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

When I run the package via the Job I get:

> "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_subdirs',
>   database 'mysqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'." Possible failure
>   reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly."

Answer (score 0):

The fictitious user needed to have a SQL Server Role of sysadmin. Well at least this works. I will have to experiment with other permissions to see what the minimal permission level I need.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/295174f9-30e8-4925-a9e5-49d073dbf3ab/executing-xpsubdirs-as-nonsysadmin?forum=sqlsecurity

Comment: Your 'fictitious' user is actually a service account user - you should make some steps to understand this better if you will regularly be using SQL Agent. It's better practice to set up a proper service account user rather than keep using NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS. I can't find a good link explaining this but maybe have a read of these: https://www.sswug.org/basitaalishanmasood-al-farooq/sql-server/understanding-the-purpose-of-sql-server-agent-part-1/  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/setting-up-your-sql-server-agent-correctly/